# How to sort all rows, one-per-group in a loop?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'd like to sort all rows in a table, one per category in a loop. For example, given the following data:

```
+---------+-------------+
| item_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
| 4013738 |        1102 |
| 4016142 |        1102 |
| 4027380 |        1102 |
| 4029166 |        1014 |
| 4031335 |        1125 |
| 4031984 |        1014 |
| 4031986 |        1014 |
| 5034654 |        1123 |
| 5034656 |        1125 |
| 5034662 |        1125 |
| 5034735 |        1109 |
| 5034736 |        1109 |
| 5034737 |        1109 |
| 5040226 |        1123 |
| 5040227 |        1123 |
+---------+-------------+
```

The desired result set should be like this:

```
+---------+-------------+
| item_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
| 4029166 |        1014 |
| 4013738 |        1102 |
| 5034735 |        1109 |
| 5034654 |        1123 |
| 4031335 |        1125 |
| 4031984 |        1014 |
| 4016142 |        1102 |
| 5034736 |        1109 |
| 5040226 |        1123 |
| 5034656 |        1125 |
| 4031986 |        1014 |
| 4027380 |        1102 |
| 5034737 |        1109 |
| 5040227 |        1123 |
| 5034662 |        1125 |
+---------+-------------+
```

The `item_id` in consecutive categories should also be ordered.  If a some categories contain more items than others, the cycle should continue the same logic with whatever rows are left.

This would be a fairly trivial task in a scripting language like php, but I can't for the life of me wrap my head around how to accomplish it in sql.

Here is a db fiddle with sample data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ioZzvoQfnSNiowe6Rp7QP5/0

Comment: I see "items" and "categories"; what is a "group"??

Comment: @RickJames - items sharing a category. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: The "desired result set" looks like the same items, simply rearranged in some order that I don't understand.  I see no dup item_ids.

Comment: @RickJames - I'm not sure what to say.  In case it's not clear in my question, the logic in the accepted answer along with Gerard's explanation should help you understand the pattern. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the category as a window, I gave the rows a number within that window, which I used then to order all the rows. In that way, I obtained all the rows that were first within their category, then all that came second, and so on. Remark that I did not order by item_id, so this may not be exactly what you need, but it should get you going.

```
with ict as (select ic.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by category_id) rn
       from item_category ic)
select item_id, category_id
  from ict
  order by ict.rn, ict.category_id;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ioZzvoQfnSNiowe6Rp7QP5/1)

Comment: I think we want the row_number within each category to be based on the item_id.  While the result appears correct, it's probably relying on the primary key or an index order.  I would suggest adding an explicit order to the window specification: `row_number() over (partition by category_id order by item_id) AS rn`.  See the following fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/14I9f7nH

Comment: Notice what happens when we change the order of the index `(item_id DESC)`.  The result with implied ordering changes, but the proposed adjustment still guarantees the expected result: https://dbfiddle.uk/o1SFNokv